# Javascript: Change Sine Wave Speed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Probably I am plain stupid but I need help with a simple thing.

I want to change the speed of the sine wave from normally 2 to 10 when a button is clicked. Nothing more, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Github Link to the SineWave.js: [Sinewave.js](https://github.com/isuttell/sine-waves)

The Code:

```
var waves = new SineWaves({
  el: document.getElementById('waves'),
  speed: 2,
  ease: 'SineInOut',
  wavesWidth: '75%',
  waves: [
    {
      timeModifier: 4,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -25,
      wavelength: 25
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 2,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -10,
      wavelength: 30
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -30,
      wavelength: 30
    },
        {
      timeModifier: 3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: 40,
      wavelength: 40
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 0.5,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -60,
      wavelength: 60
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1.3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -40,
      wavelength: 40
    }
  ],

  resizeEvent: function() {
    var gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(25, 255, 255, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(255, 25, 255, 0.75)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255, 255, 25, 0");

    var index = -1;
    var length = this.waves.length;
      while(++index < length){
      this.waves[index].strokeStyle = gradient;
    }

    index = void 0;
    length = void 0;
    gradient = void 0;
  }
});
```

A Codepen Example:

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxEKJZ?editors=1010
```

Please help me, I am dying right now because of this...
(and its probably even a small change)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   *If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses jQuery:

```js
var waves = new SineWaves({
  el: document.getElementById('waves'),
  speed: 2,
  ease: 'SineInOut',
  wavesWidth: '75%',
  waves: [
    {
      timeModifier: 4,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -25,
      wavelength: 25
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 2,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -10,
      wavelength: 30
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -30,
      wavelength: 30
    },
  {
      timeModifier: 3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: 40,
      wavelength: 40
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 0.5,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -60,
      wavelength: 60
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1.3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -40,
      wavelength: 40
    }
  ],
 
  resizeEvent: function() {
    var gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(25, 255, 255, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(255, 25, 255, 0.75)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255, 255, 25, 0");
    
    var index = -1;
    var length = this.waves.length;
   while(++index < length){
      this.waves[index].strokeStyle = gradient;
    }
    
    index = void 0;
    length = void 0;
    gradient = void 0;
  }
});

$("#change_speed").click(function(){
 waves.options.speed = 10;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://isuttell.github.io/sine-waves/javascripts/sine-waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="waves" width="300" height="180"></canvas>
<button id='change_speed'>Change Speed</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of changing colors if you aren't trying to preserve the gradient via the `resizeEvent` function:

```js
var waves = new SineWaves({
  el: document.getElementById('waves'),
  speed: 2,
  ease: 'SineInOut',
  wavesWidth: '75%',
  waves: [{
      timeModifier: 4,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -25,
      wavelength: 25,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 2,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -10,
      wavelength: 30,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -30,
      wavelength: 30,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: 40,
      wavelength: 40,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 0.5,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -60,
      wavelength: 60,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1.3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -40,
      wavelength: 40,
      strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    }
  ]
});

$("#change_color").click(function() {
  waves.waves[0].strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)';
  waves.waves[1].strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)';
  waves.waves[2].strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)';
  waves.waves[3].strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)';
  waves.waves[4].strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 225, 0.9)';
  waves.waves[5].strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9)';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://isuttell.github.io/sine-waves/javascripts/sine-waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="waves" width="300" height="180"></canvas>
<button id='change_color'>Change Color</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the example too. But I if you can shortly answer me another question: Is this possible with the color of the waves too?

Comment: That's a bit trickier, as the color is set using a gradient in the `resizeEvent` function rather than through a static color attribute.  You would need to update the function, but after a quick try, I wasn't able to get this working.

Comment: Okey thanks you for the answer. I will try to change the function that the color is set as an static attribute.

Comment: Take a look at my update that shows how to set static colors and change them with a button click.

Comment: Wow.. I dont know how to thank you more. This is great and so are you. <3

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your waves object you will see it has a speed parameter inside options and thus you can change the speed liek this:

```
<button onclick="waves.options.speed = 10;">hmmm</button>
```

Comment: I have one more question: Would this work for the color too?

Comment: It certainly looks like it, although this would be more complicated.

Comment: I am really sorry to further bother you, but can you give me any keywords to search for? Or give me an example? And I really apreciate the work you already done for me :)

Comment: You need to set the stroke style against the waves. You will probably need to use the ctx from the wave object to do something similar to resizeEvent function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You really helped me, I will try to figure this out now ^^